# change certain values from one list to another python

Tags: python

i have two lists

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'NO DATA',8,9,10]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0]
```

So i need to change 7th element in `list1` to 7th element from `list2`

I need to define this:

```
for x in list1:
    if x == 'NO DATA':
```

*need to change `x[index]` from `list1` to `x[index]` from `list2`*

how i can make this?

so i need to have final list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: `list3 = [(i, j)[i == 'NO DATA'] for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One fairly simple way to do that:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'NO DATA',8,9,10]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0]


def get_item(x,y):
    if x == "NO DATA":
        return y
    return x

[get_item(x, y) for (x,y) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

please try it:

```
import copy


list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'NO DATA',8,9,10]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0]

list3 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
pattern = 'NO DATA'
for i, x in enumerate(list1):
    if x == pattern:
        list3[i] = list2[i]

print(list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,'NO DATA',8,9,10]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0]

index=list1.index('NO DATA')

list3=list1[:index]+list2[index:index+1]+list1[index+1:]
```

Comment: What if there're few occurences of `'NO DATA'`?

Comment: I have posted another answer for more than one 'No data'

Answer (score 1):

```
  i=0
  for a,b in zip(x,y):
     if a=='No data':
            x[i]=b
     i+=1
```